# Why can't I reduce Brazil's neutrality in Hearts of Iron 3: For the Motherland?

Tags: hearts-of-iron-3, for-the-motherland

I'm playing my first game of Hearts of Iron 3, I'm playing as Brazil. I've gotten to the stage where I've figured out enough of the interface, but I now want to try have a war so I can figure out the military system.

Since Brazil is a dictatorship, I thought this would be easy, but I can't because my neutrality is too high. So I looked up the [Brazil strategy guide](http://www.paradoxian.org/hoi3wiki/Brazil_strategy_guide) on the wiki.

It states:

> On the domestic front, spies should be used to lower neutrality in order to allow Brazil to expand and conquer its neighbours.

However, it appears not to have been updated since the initial release of Hearts of Iron III. I am playing with the Semper Fi and For The Motherland expansion packs, and that button is simply not there. My options for spies are Counter Intelligence, supporting my ruling party or increasing national unity. And that's it. I know that there is sometimes an option "Lower our Neutrality", but it's just not there in my game.

Which means there must be some pre-condition to using this option that I'm not aware of. I've searched the wiki, and there is no reference to any. Since most of the wiki hasn't been updated for For The Motherland, I'm guessing it's to do with the expansion pack.

**tl;dr**: What do you need to do before using the lower neutrality option for spies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like in the Motherland expansion that option was removed to increase reliance on events.

Answer (score 2):

You should send your spies to increase threat to get your neutrality lowered. You could increase the threat of UK efficiently since they have land areas next to Brazil.

I used this trick to get Brazil to join the Axis after a few years. When the war starts you can have fun in South America for a while until the Allies make a landing.